# Change format to Special - Chinese (locale)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to edit format setting for a cell (preferable for entire column ) to have a Special Format first item for Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan). 
How can I do it through VBA?
 [image]

I have tried with `Format(string, "[$-404]") 'so called LCID but it doesn't working`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a 3 digit format:

```
activecell.NumberFormat = "000"
```